# Caption on side of page

Tags: floats, captions, rotating, landscape

I have a image that I want to include in my thesis.  It's long, so I have to rotate it, however when I do this the caption remains at the bottom of the page.  How can I make the caption go to the side of the page, so it's under the image still?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [rotating](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package; here's a little example (I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` just to make my example compilable for everyone; don't include that option in your actual document)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{image}
  \caption{a rotated figure.}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to use the [hvfloat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
  objectAngle=90,%
  capAngle=90,%
  capPos=r,%
  capVPos=t,%
  capWidth=h]{figure}%
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{image}}%
  {a rotated figure.}{fig:test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this and the entire page was rotated...

Comment: @devin: I added another solution. I don't understand your comment; such a non descriptive message is not useful. Was my solution useful for you or not? If not, why? Which was the result you were expecting?

Comment: The hvfloat solution works perfectly for me.  What I meant with the first comment was that I tried the sidewaysfigure technique and it rotated not only the image but the entire page.  So in my pdf view all my pages were portrait except the one with the image on it, which was landscape.

Comment: @devin: then, if you want to, you can accept my answer using the green check mark to the left.